# How to enable Push Notification for node using Firebase service FCM

Tags: firebase, express, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

As I have codebase in which I'm using Express library with template engine PUG(foremely jade) and I just want to integrate **web push notification** on a API call with the response of JSON data of which should show to the user irrespective of page he has open.

I have setup a project on firebase console and enable both FCM services.

Just wanted to know where should I write its SDK configuration in project and how to take device token of users where the notification should show.